# JS Slider cant change image animate time

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm developed the **image slide show** . I want to change slider **animate time**. but **can't change image animate time**, how can i fix it?please help me ,i;m submit my code please check it, I want to animate, 2 minutes in one image

**function**

```
(function($, document, window){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // Cloning main navigation for mobile menu
        $(".mobile-navigation").append($(".main-navigation .menu").clone());

        // Mobile menu toggle 
        $(".menu-toggle").click(function(){
            $(".mobile-navigation").slideToggle();
        });

        $(".offer img, .news img").panr({
            sensitivity: 150,
            scale: false,
            scaleOnHover: true,
            scaleTo: 50.2,
            scaleDuration: 55.25,
            panY: true,
            panX: true,
            panDuration: 50.25,
            resetPanOnMouseLeave: false
        });

        $(".testimonial-slider, .hero-slider").flexslider({
            directionNav: false,
            controlNav: true
        });

        if( $(".map").length ) {
            $('.map').gmap3({
                map: {
                    options: {
                        maxZoom: 14,
                        scrollwheel: false
                    }  
                },
                marker:{
                    address: "40 Sibley St, Detroit",
                    // options: {
                    //  icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                    //      "images/map-marker.png",
                    //      new google.maps.Size(43, 53, "px", "px")
                    //  )
                    // }
                }
            },
            "autofit" );

        }
    });

    $(window).load(function(){

    });

})(jQuery, document, window);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are having issues with flexslider, have you looked at the documentation (slideshowSpeed)?

https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties#slideshowspeed